# Cognito permission to lambda function using serverless framework

Tags: permissions, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I tried giving my lambda function permission to access Cognito and also to invoke another lambda function using the following code in my serverless.yml file. 
The code :

```
# NOTE: update this with your service name
service: xxxx

# Use the serverless-webpack plugin to transpile ES6
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline

# serverless-webpack configuration
# Enable auto-packing of external modules
custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: ap-south-1

  environment:
    MYSQLHOST: 'xxxx'
    MYSQLPORT: 'xxxx'
    MYSQLUSER: 'xxxx'
    MYSQLPASS: 'xxxx'
    MYSQLDATABASE: 'xxxx'
    USERPOOLID: 'xxxx'
    USERPOOLREGION: 'xxxx'
  # To load environment variables externally
  # rename env.example to env.yml and uncomment
  # the following line. Also, make sure to not
  # commit your env.yml.
  #
  #environment: ${file(env.yml):${self:provider.stage}}
Version: "2012-10-17"

iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
      -cognito-identity:*
      -cognito-sync:*
      -cognito-idp:*
      -lambda:*
    Resource:
      -"*"


functions:
  # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in create.js
  # - path: url path is /notes
  # - method: POST request
  # - cors: enabled CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for browser cross
  #     domain api call
  # - authorizer: authenticate using the AWS IAM role

  createUser:
    handler: createUser.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: users/create
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam

  getUsers:
    handler: getUsers.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: getUsers
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

When I added the permissions for dynamodb , those got added to my lambda Role.But the cognito permissions arent getting attached to the role.

The Serverless Framework , handles the creation of role on its own , based on the yml file.
Once the role gets created , I can add the policy through the AWS console.
But the framework doesn't create them even after specifying.

Comment: try adding "Version": "2012-10-17" to your policy

Comment: I tried adding Version to the serverless.yml file , still no help. The role gets created but with no cognito and lambda permissions.

Comment: You have to attach the policy to your cognito auth role. How are you assigning this policy that you created?

Comment: I have edited my question , to give you more insights to it .Thanks.

Comment: You can check the artifacts (cloudformation template) within .serverless folder as stated on https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/ It should give you insight into what the problem might be if it's not related to the actual deployment. If it's related to the deployment, then you can try to run ```sls package -v``` to get verbose output which may help you figure out what's going wrong. Also check the IAM console https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_understand-service-summary.html to find out any unrecognized resource type or action etc.

Comment: `iamRoleStatements` is not top level configuration and should be under `provider`. Is this a posting mistake?

Comment: Also lambda functions shouldn't invoke other lambda functions (according to best practice). Use SQS or even S3:putobject events